# boot hangs and needs manual 'lvm vgchange -ay'

Tags: 16.04, raid, lvm

My machine has two identical disks in mirror mode using (software) raid and then lvm.

When rebooting, eg after a power loss, the machine fails to recognise the lvm partition and drops into an initramfs / busybox shell.

Once I *manually* enter `lvm vgchange -ay` and `continue` it all proceeds.  How do I change or update my boot config to make this automagic?

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same issue. Have you already found a solution for that?

Comment: Yes, as I my question shows:   say `lvm vgchange -a` and `continue`.  I have yet to alter `grub` etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are you using GRUB Legacy to boot your system? I have chosen to upgrade GRUB Legacy to GRUB2, which solved the issue completely for me. Before I tried to set the `rootdelay` variable to 60 seconds (there are LVM snapshots in my root vg), but that did not solve the issue.

Comment: Sadly I use grub2 and still have the issue. (Though I haven't (had to) reboot in a while.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news, it is fixed with 16.10.  I actually didn't reboot since posting the question (and the power grid here in Illinois stayed up that long...)

With today's (belated) upgrade to 16.10, I also re-read a few threads on the internet.  The long bug report thread about the issue at [Debian bug report #616689](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=616689) contains this recommendation somewhere further down:

```
cat /boot/grub/device.map
sudo grub-mkdevicemap
cat /boot/grub/device.map
```

and I think this mattered.  The first `cat` showed two entries corresponding to an old setup with my initial two drives. One of those dies and was replaced (yay, lvm saved the day there andmade that easy!)
but the entry never was updated.  Running `grub-mkdevicemap` may have fixed it.

In any event, no more manually attended reboots with 16.10.

Comment: Glad this worked for you; no change or improvement here, though. So there's other reasons for this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this on 16.04.  My setup is boot off a mirror and then / is LVM with multiple partitions within seperate lv's all in the same volume group.

The problem I had (which made me tear my hair out) was upon reboot it would throw me to initramfs shell.

From there I needed to run vgchange -a y and ctrl-d and system would boot up.

I scoured the web and came across some suggestions ranging from:

bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lvm2/+bug/147216

```
2) Adding this to /etc/udev/rules.d/85-lvm2.rules solved the problem.

SUBSYSTEM=="block", ACTION=="add|change", ENV{ID_FS_USAGE}="raid", \
 RUN+="watershed sh -c '/sbin/lvm vgscan; /sbin/lvm vgchange -a y'"
```

to:

bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=616689

But the solution for me was to strip down the suggestion from this guy

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lvm2/+bug/147216/comments/22

and make the following change.

add `/sbin/lvm vgchange -a y`

to /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-block/lvm2

(I also copied it to /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-block/)

then I ran `` #update-initramfs -u -k `uname -r` ``

rebooted and finally back to sanity.

Comment: this also worked for me in 16.04.2, without the copying to (`/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-block/`)