# boot hangs and needs manual 'lvm vgchange -aay'

Tags: boot, 22.04, lvm

Related to [boot hangs and needs manual 'lvm vgchange -ay'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794526/boot-hangs-and-needs-manual-lvm-vgchange-ay) but still present in 22.04:

I have an encrypted boot volume, followed by LVM root.

Every boot, the other LVM volumes get activated automatically, but I have to enter
`lvm vgchange -aay` for the LVM root to be activated, before boot can continue.

- The /boot/grub/device.map is stable, no updates by grub-mkdevicemap
- /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-block/lvm2 contains the `lvchange_activate() { lvm lvchange -aay -y --sysinit --ignoreskippedcluster "$@" }` function already
- auto_activation_volume_list in /etc/lvm/lvm.conf is not set (as opposed to empty), so all available volumes should be activated

So, what else is to be done about this?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed by some patch to Ubuntu 22.04 during 2022.

Current Ubuntu doesn't seem to have that issue anymore.
I wish us luck this thing doesn't return.